# How to indent in vim for designated initializers?

Tags: c, vim, indentation, designated-initializer

How to do proper indentation in vim for designated initializers of structs (in C)?

This is how it is indented by default:

```
typedef struct {
    int foo;
    int bar;
} child_t;

typedef struct {
    child_t child;
} parent_t;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    parent_t p;
    p.child = (child_t) {
        .foo = 1,
            .bar = 2,
    };
}
```

How can I have it indented like this?

```
typedef struct {
    int foo;
    int bar;
} child_t;

typedef struct {
    child_t child;
} parent_t;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    parent_t p;
    p.child = (child_t) {
        .foo = 1,
        .bar = 2,
    };
}
```

I've tried quite a few options from https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/indent.html but haven't been able to make it work.

Removing `(child_t)` allows it to do indent properly, but in that case the gcc compiler complains with an `expected expression before ‘{’ token` error message (because apparently it isn't able to infer what type `p.child` is.

Comment: If you remove the `(child_t)` it's no longer a compound literal but invalid syntax.

Comment: I don't know how to fix the indentation in `vim`. In this special case you could initialize `p` where you define it without using the type specification. As a workaround you could use a variable of type `child_t` for a structure field  assignment. `parent_t p;` `child_t c = { ... };` `p.child = c;`.

Comment: You can send the content of the file to `clang-format` (https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) with `:%!clang-format`.

Comment: @Tekki and then .clang-format based on LLVM?

Comment: @AnnevanRossum  Depends on your preferences. I have "BasedOnStyle: Google" in my `~/.clang-format`.

Comment: Note sure, how easy it is, but would also be nice to know how to do so without external tools.

Answer (score 0):

If you use vim and want propper formatting, I can recomd to use `coc` vim and ccls. Further you can use `clang-format` to format your source files propperly.